# bootstrap dismiss button not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a boostrap alert that pops up upon form submission via jquery, but the dismiss button overlaps with the text and I cannot figure out why. I am not styling the alert or the button. Screenshot of the error and code being used below:

[screesnhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqiKx.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap has alert box functionality built in, you shouldn't need to use any custom jQuery to construct it.

Comment: not sure why but this code would not display correctly i nthe orignal question - this is the alert box: var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there's no need to build the alert in jQuery since it's already built into Bootstrap. The only thing you should be using jQuery for is to show the alert on submit of the form:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.alert').show();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.alert {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you!
      </div>

      <form id="contact-form">
        <label>Name: <input type="text"/></label>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will also work if you construct the alert as a JavaScript variable:

```js
$(function() {
  var messageText = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you!';
  var alertBox = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + messageText + '</div>';
  
  $('.col-sm-10').append(alertBox);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you are saying, but I'm really just curious why the alert box I am constructing is working except for the dismiss button.

Comment: Also, if I just set the alert to show and reset the form, when I close the alert and resubmit the form the alert will be gone.

Comment: If you construct it using HTML, it will work correctly, as you can see in my example above. It will work even if you construct it as a JavaScript variable, though there's no reason to do that. I have updated my answer to reflect that method as well.

Comment: weird, even following your new code the dismiss button still displays incorrectly: https://imgur.com/a/cxc5VqN

Comment: Do you have any CSS that would be overriding those elements? Also, be sure you're using latest Bootstrap 4.

Comment: looks like I just had improperly implemented some of your code, working now. thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have its own alert and dismiss class. You dont need to use any Jquery plugin for this. Try this code

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you!.
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed a tutorial and the reason for the jquery is to reset the php form and throw an alert stating if the submission succeeded or not. Either way, the alert box works, it's just the dismiss box that is displaying weirdly.

Comment: If you want to rest the form. Why dont you just add the Reset button along side with submit. and the the value to reset. So the form will be automatically reset.

Comment: You can Also reset your form by submit button. When submit is success the run a function which will automatically reset the field.